# shell script to read one line and process line by line

Tags: bash, shell, line

I have below file with fqdn of server & user of that server in same line.
cat servers.txt

```
server1 user1 \n
server2 user2 \n
server3 user3 \n
```

I am writing a shell script where I can use one server at a time to do ssh and perform some commands there and move to next server in line. For example, ssh to server1 and sudo to user1 and do the stuff, than move to server2.
So I written below and tried to tweak but no workaround found. Its not working. Please help.

```
ROOT_PATH=/home
SERVERS_FILE=servers.txt

while IFS= read -r line; do
        server=`cut -d' ' -f1 $line`
        user=`cut -d' ' -f2 $line`
        echo $server ::: $user
        echo "grep -rw lookeupword $ROOT_PATH/$user" | ssh $server "sudo -iu $user bash"
done <<< "$SERVERS_FILE"
```

Comment: note that each server and its user at on a new line.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_?

Comment: meaning it give me error when tries to ssh on host from first variable $server. Check below.

ROOT_PATH=/home
SERVERS_FILE=servers.txt
while IFS= read -r line; do
#       echo $line
        server=$(echo -n ${line} | awk '{print $1}')
        user=$(echo -n ${line} | awk '{print $2}')
        echo $server ::: $user
        echo "grep -rw findtheword $ROOT_PATH/$user" | ssh $server "sudo -iu $user bash"
done <<< "$SERVERS_FILE"
I tried above but it fails with that ssh command. throws below error.
servers.txt :::
ssh: Could not resolve hostname servers.txt: Name or service not known

Comment: The error message should be written into the question, not in a comment ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ROOT_PATH=/home
SERVERS_FILE=servers.txt

while IFS= read -r line; do
        server=$(echo -n ${line} | awk '{print $1}')
        user=$(echo -n ${line} | awk '{print $2}')
        echo $server ::: $user
        #echo "grep -rw lookeupword $ROOT_PATH/$user" | ssh $server "sudo -iu $user bash"
done < "$SERVERS_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using a **one liner** here is a simple one

**First** create `.ssh/config` file and setup configuration for each `Host` you have. here is mine (some part of it)

```
Host docker
    HostName X.X.X.X
    port XXXX
    user root

Host nginx
    HostName X.X.X.X
    port XXXX
    user root

Host dw
    HostName X.X.X.X
    port XXXX
    user root
```

So ssh(ing) to **docker**, **nginx**, **dw** without password is possible (using public/private key).
**Second** loop over those `Host` you have or want to run a command:

```
xargs -I xxx ssh xxx ip -br a < hosts
```

here is a simple screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is possible but I already has config file set for all servers. But I wants to use the file which has server name and user to login in same line separated by space. I wants to run find command on each of the server by using servername and user to switch to.